# why does TestNG execute @AfterMethod as a @Test if my first test is passed?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

why does TestNG execute @AfterMethod as a @Test if my first test is passed?

For example the testoutput if my first test fails is:

```
1 test passed, 1 test failed.(3599,0 s)
    TestSuite FAILED
        run FAILED: check5=3 Expected: <3> got: <5>
        run passed (1.0s)
```

But if I just switch the order of test cases, so the first will pass, i get this:

```
3 test passed, 2 test failed.(2867,0 s)
    TestSuite FAILED
        run passed (1.0s)
        run FAILED: check5=3 Expected: <3> got: <5>
        AfterMethod FAILED (4,0 s) // <--- wtf, this is not an @Test
        AfterTest passed (5,0 s)
        AfterSuite passed (15,0 s)
```

what is happening? my testngsuite.xml:

```
<suite name="TestSuite_03">
    <test name="TestCase_17">
        <groups>
            <run><include name="functest"/></run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="TestStep_003" desc="will pass" />
            <class name="TestStep_012" desc="will fail" />
        </classes> ...
```

I am using Maven, TestNG and Java via NetBeans

my structure:

```
public abstract class TestCommon
{
    @BeforeSuite(groups={"functest"})
    public void BeforeSuite()
    {
        // clean report folder
    }
    @BeforeTest(groups={"functest"})
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        // start selenium browser
    }
    @AfterMethod(groups={"functest"}) // this is not a @test, still gets shown as failed
    public void AfterMethod()
    {
        // check for failure and capture screenshot
    }
    @AfterTest(groups={"functest})
    public void AfterTest()
    {
        // close browser
    }
}


public class TestStep_003 extends TestCommon
{
    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void run()
    {
        assertThat(5, Matchers.equalTo(5)); // will pass
    }
}
public class TestStep_012 extends TestCommon
{
    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void run()
    {
        assertThat(5, Matchers.equalTo(3)); // will fail
    }
}
```

Annother issue is that the testoutput is not in order, the timestamps are
not older -> newer, there are newer ones between old ones:
thats how my output looks like:

```
1327840359762:  TestStep_012.AfterMethod // this is not the oldest timestamp!
1327840359763:  TestStep_003.run 
1327840359765:  TestStep_003.AfterMethod
1327840357189:  TestStep_012.BeforeSuite
1327840357192:  TestStep_012.BeforeTest
1327840359758:  TestStep_012.run 
1327840359762:  TestStep_012.AfterMethod
1327840359763:  TestStep_003.run 
1327840359765:  TestStep_003.AfterMethod
```

furthermore, there are only 2 methods TestStep_003.run and and TestStep_012.run,
and still it shows AfterMethod 4x

Comment: What are you using to run your TestNG tests? This output doesn't look like TestNG's native output.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. the timestamp output is just a echo method using system.out.println with the current date and printing out the name of the class and method to get an idea of the test-flow.
may be i made a logical mistake in my strucutre. All i want is bascially a superclass to start the browser upon test-start and close the browser on test-end, so all test classes in between the <test> do use the same browser. and a new <test> would use a new browser again.

Comment: i dont understand whats happening, because if the first test is failed the TestNG output and my debug output is in order and exactly as i want it. but if the first test is passed, its all messed up. both tests are equal, except the asserThat for 1 pass and 1 fail.

Comment: would you mind checking why the report shows AfterSuite as passed though its not an @Test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test passed but action did not happen selenium webdriver + testng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406655/test-passed-but-action-did-not-happen-selenium-webdriver-testng)